# why am I getting this error true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to find a character a and then a character z 3 or less characters away from it in a string here is my code below:

```
def nearby_az(string)
  ind1 = string.index(?a)
  while ind1 != nil
    return ((ind2=string.index(?z,ind1)!=nil) and ((ind2-ind1) <= 3))  #if there is a z and ind bt a and z is
    #less than or equal to 3 then return true
    ind1 = string.index(?a,ind1)
  end
  return false      #can't find any a characters in the string
end
```

but I get this error:

```
07-most-letters.rb:10:in `nearby_az': undefined method `-' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)                                                                                                 
        from 07-most-letters.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `z` must follow `a`, then consider this:

```
def nearby_az(str)
  (ia = str.index('a')) && (iz = str.index('z', ia)) && iz - ia <= 3
end

nearby_az("There is alwzys the..") #=> true
nearby_az("There is always zee..") #=> false
nearby_az("There'z always the..")  #=> nil
```

If you would like to always return `true` or `false` (and not the falsy value `nil`), change the operative line to:

```
!!((ia = str.index('a')) && (iz = str.index('z', ia)) && iz - ia <= 3)
```

If `z` could precede or follow `a`, then modify as follows:

```
def nearby_az(str)
  (ia = str.index('a')) && (iz = str.index('z', [ia-3,0].max)) &&
    (iz - ia).abs <= 3
end

nearby_az("There is alwzys the..") #=> true
nearby_az("There is always zee..") #=> false
nearby_az("There'z always the..")  #=> true
```

Comment: thanks!! thats so concise and neat. I really wanted to try to solve the problem without all the if else branching.

Comment: what does the [ia-3,0].max do?

Comment: We don't want to try to start the `index` search at a negative index.  If `ia = 7`, `[7-3,0].max => 4`; if `ia = 2`, `[2-3,0].max => 0`.

Answer (score 1):

At `((ind2=string.index(?z,ind1)!=nil)`, you're setting `ind2` to `string.index(?z,ind1)!=nil`, which is a boolean value. You can group `ind2=string.index(?z,ind1)` to avoid this:

```
return (((ind2=string.index(?z,ind1))!=nil) and ((ind2-ind1) <= 3))
```